# How to resolve the invalid number in orcale

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]
I am facing an issue with some data that start with a strange character  before the number 5
how can I discover all of these characters and remove it

```
5,AX,AMEX,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
DM,BSHB,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,MC,
BSHB,1,323.50,0,0,0,0,1,P1,
BSHB,81,7819.25,0,0,0,0,81,
VC,BSHB,5,212.95,0,0,0,0,5
```

what do you recommend to resolve this issue knowing that I get the data from a specific source so I can not change anything but I am trying to mask it in the view?

Comment: The character does not appear in the post

Comment: Are you saying that your table contains a string column and in these strings there may be control characters that you want to remove from the strings with an update?

Comment: No in the column let's suppose X, X has some records like the data in the post but some of them have a strange character that causes the issue before number 5. I can not display the character here it is a square @ThorstenKettner

Comment: what exactly is your used code? this is just a list of values .....

Comment: @MichaelHauptmann it is a normal select

Comment: So, your post shows one string, yes? It contains letters, digits, commas, line feeds, and some invisible character. You want to remove this invisible character. Yes?

Comment: @MichaelHauptmann select X from bankaccount where id = 000

Comment: You can `select dump(X) from bankaccount where id = 000` to see the character codes in the string for a start.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner actually it is visible in the oracle but it can not be defined it like a square, but as I said before I can not show it here in the post

Comment: How do you parse those strings?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner --  ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I did not even try to break it up. it is just a normal select column then the name of it and one condition where the id equals something. the problem in the source I have no idea how can I remove the first character

Comment: @MaramA-zaid show us `desc bankaccount`. Looks like ID is not a number column

Comment: You cannot get an exception by merely selecting x, no matter what it contains. x would have to be used in some expression for this to happen. Please show the complete query. If you are getting this with the query shown, than the only reason for this exception I can think of is `id` not being a numeric column. You get all except the first character with `substr(x, 2)` by the way.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  I have imported an image to show you the character that I meant the issue not from the ID or parsing

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I have imported an image to show you the character that I meant the issue not from the ID or parsing

Comment: @MichaelHauptmann I have imported an image to show you the character that I meant the issue not from the ID or parsing

Comment: As mentioned: You ***cannot*** get this exception with the query shown because of the strange character in x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regexp_replace can always help to find or replace/remove any characters you want.

For example, if you want to delete all characters escept alphanumeric, space, comma and dot:

`regexp_replace(t.str,'[^ ,.[:alnum:]]')`

Comment: Yes, regexp_replace is a good method for removing unwanted characters. But your expression would also remove the CR and LF.

Comment: ok how I can specify the character that is shown in the image

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, as I said (except alphanum,space,commas and dots) :) if you do not want to delete new line characters you can just add modifier 'M': `regexp_replace(t.str,'[^ ,.[:alnum:]]','',1,0,'m')`

Comment: @MaramA-zaid you do not specify that characters, you just need to specify characters that you want to keep